# How to add operator and email notification on all the SQL jobs?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

To be more proactive and responsive to the job issues or failures I want to set an alert, add operator and send the notification(to me) when a job fails. I know Operator and notification can be added through SSMS GUI but its a very time-consuming process and can be prone to errors so I am trying to do it through scripting. The following script gives me jobs

```
USE msdb
SELECT sj.name AS JobName,
    CASE
    WHEN sj.enabled = 1 THEN 'Enable'
    ELSE 'Disable'
    END AS JobStatus,
    sj.description AS JobDescription,
    ss.name AS JobScheduleName,
    CASE
    WHEN ss.enabled = 1 THEN 'Enable'
    WHEN ss.enabled = 0 THEN 'Disable'
    ELSE 'Not Schedule'
    END AS JobScheduleStatus, 
    --ss.active_start_date AS ActiveStartDate,
    --ss.active_end_date AS ActiveEndDate,
    --ss.active_start_time AS ActiveStartTime,
    --ss.active_end_time AS ActiveEndTime,
    sh.step_name AS StepName,
    Case 
       sh.run_status WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Success'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
       WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress' END AS Status,
    dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) As Last_Run_DateTime,
    sh.run_duration AS RunDuration,
     ((run_duration/10000*3600 + (run_duration/100)%100*60 + run_duration%100 + 31) / 60) as 'RunDurationMinutes'
FROM dbo.sysjobs AS sj
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysjobschedules AS sjs ON sj.job_id = sjs.job_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysschedules AS ss ON sjs.schedule_id = ss.schedule_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysjobhistory AS sh ON sj.job_id = sh.job_id
```

I also made an attempt in adding operator, please correct me if I am doing it wrong.

```
DECLARE @Operator varchar(50)
SET @Operator = 'Emamr'
SELECT  sj.job_id AS JobID,
        sj.name AS JobName,
        sj.description AS JobDescription,
        ----adding operator using SP----
       'EXEC sp_update_job @job_name = ''' + sj.[name] + 
       ''', @notify_email_operator_name = ''' + @Operator  +
       ''', @notify_level_email = 2' As OperatorAdded  -- 1 = On Success, 2 = On Failure,3=always
FROM dbo.sysjobs sj
WHERE sj.enabled = 1 
AND sj.notify_level_email <> 1
```

After adding the operator I need to set an email notification and I don't know how to do that in one script. Any help or guidance will be appreciated

Made another attempt still not working for me.

```
DECLARE @Operator varchar(100)
DECLARE @Alert VARCHAR(100)
SET @Operator = 'Emamr'
SELECT 
    @@SERVERNAME AS 'ServerName', ----added just in case you need it----
    sj.job_id AS JobID,
    sj.name AS JobName,
    CASE
    WHEN sj.enabled = 1 THEN 'Enable'
    ELSE 'Disable'
    END AS JobStatus,
    sj.notify_level_email,
    so.name As Operator

From dbo.sysjobs AS sj 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysjobschedules AS sjs ON sj.job_id = sjs.job_id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysoperators so ON sj.notify_email_operator_id = so.id
  WHERE sj.enabled = '1' AND sj.name= 'Test2'
    AND sj.notify_level_email = '0'
SELECT @Alert =' EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job 
                      @job_ID = ''' + convert(varchar(50),job_id) + ''',
                      @notify_level_email = 2, 
                      @notify_email_operator_name = ''' + @operator + '''; '
                        + char (10) + @Alert
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
--PRINT @Alert
--executing the statement
EXEC (@Alert)
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working at the moment? Doesn't setting @notify_level_email solve your issue?

Comment: @George.Palacios SP is working separately but I want to execute the SP along with the first query and when I do that, its not working.

Answer (score 2):

When you script out the process of adding a notification, you get something like this:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id='01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef', 
    @notify_level_email=2, 
    @notify_level_netsend=2, 
    @notify_level_page=2, 
    @notify_email_operator_name=N'MyOperator'
```

If you performed a SELECT against the `msdb.dbo.sysjobs` table, you should be able to generate all of the TSQL code to do this for you, e.g.

```
SELECT 'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id=''' + Cast(job_id AS VARCHAR(40)) + ''',
    @notify_level_email=2, 
    @notify_level_netsend=2, 
    @notify_level_page=2, 
    @notify_email_operator_name=N''MyOperator''
GO'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

Comment: I tried but still not working